# Google Drive file download API failure

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, postman

I have an app which prints files from a Google drive account. It uses the API https://drive.google.com/uc?id=&export=download to download the content and sends for printing. Instead of downloading the correct content some junk characters are being downloaded from the last two days. I tried this API in postman and got the same result.

```
HttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url("drive.google.com/…)
             .get().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx"")
             .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
             .addHeader("Postman-Token", "02efaa73-543e-4b02-bbd4-570cfbd3f9f4") 
             .build(); 
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Without seeing your code it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Here is the request I tried in Postman:

Comment: OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1P1J6e8r_CoKc_CJDVdmBsQHzEp28orRu&export=download")
  .get()
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx"")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "02efaa73-543e-4b02-bbd4-570cfbd3f9f4")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();